# multiplication in django in django

Tags: django, activerecord-calculations

how do i multiply two numbers in a budget model for example i want to multiply labour hours and rate per hour ...Then after i add that figure to the total cost of everything ..please help

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .directors import Directors

class ApprovedBudget(models.Model):
  job=models.CharField(max_length=255)
  time=models.DateTimeField()
  labourhours=models.IntegerField()
  rate=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  materials=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  travel=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  other=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  notes=models.CharField(max_length=450)
  budget=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  actual=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  undercover=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=12,default='pending')
  #pending,approved,rejected,cancelled 
  is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  #hide
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False) created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
  
  objects = Directors()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = (ApprovedBudget)
    verbose_name_plural = ('ApprovedBudget')
  
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.job)
  
  @property
  def labour(self):
    if(self.labourhours != None ):
      labour=self.labourhours*self.rate
      return labour
```

Comment: What is problem in provided code it's looking correct

Comment: i  am not seeing the change in the admin showing the calculation result of labourhours multiplied by rate , when i try to add labour in the filter it says its not callable

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton check my answer and let me know if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding `save()` method of model.
First add one extra field to your model to store multiplied value  like this

```
class ApprovedBudget(models.Model):
    .....all other fields
    labour = models.IntegerField(blank=True)#set blank=True so it will not raise any validation error while creating object

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if(self.labourhours != None ):
        self.labour=self.labourhours*self.rate
        super(ApprovedBudget, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if you don't want to store it in database and just want to display on admin interface than do like this

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ApprovedBudgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = [..all your fields, 'labour_cost']
      
      def labour_cost(self, obj):
          if obj.labourhours and obj.rate:
             return self.labourhours*self.rate
          return 'None'
```

Comment: let me try thanks

Comment: Thanks Ankit it is able to create a filter under the title 'save' however it is not calculating the labour hours multiplied by the rate

Comment: its producing a null value

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton you want to store your multiplied value in database or you just want to display it ?

Comment: i want to store it in the database

Comment: Okk then check I've edited my answer

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton may I know where you're trying to save your multiplied value. I can't find any attribute where you want to store.

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton let me know if it worked.

Comment: how do i  override save() method ii am getting this error <class 'approvedbudget.admin.Task'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'labour', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'Task', or an attribute or method on 'approvedbudget.ApprovedBudget'.

Comment: in admin  and models my code is like this from django.contrib import admin

from .models import ApprovedBudget

class Task(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('job', 'time', 'labourhours','rate','labour','materials','travel','other','notes','budget','actual','undercover')


admin.site.register(ApprovedBudget,Task)

Comment: @property
def labour(self, *args, **kwargs):
  if(self.labourhours != None ):
    self.labour=self.labourhours*self.rate
    super(ApprovedBudget, self).labour(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton you want to display multiplied value on admin panel or you want to store it in database?

Comment: Hello @TamieClayton check I've edited my answer

Comment: it has managed to add a field name labour however if i dont put a figure in the field labour it produces this error Exception Type:  IntegrityError
Exception Value:  

NOT NULL constraint failed: approvedbudgets_approvedbudget.labour.

Comment: and when it multiplied 20 by 5 it produced 20 and when it multiplied 10 by 5 it produced 12